# What's wrong with my dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am currently learning CSS and HTML and I wanted to build a basic dropdown menu using CSS only. There are some things that I don't understand if someone could help me figure out what is going on.

Here's how it looks

http://liveweave.com/eTdt7V

Why is my Menu 1 being pushed at the top of the nav? How can I avoid that? 
Why is my Submenu 1 to the right of the Menu 1? How do I fix it? 
The height of my submenu is overflowing over the first UL. Is that supposed to be?

Hopefully someone can help me understand what's going on here that would be a valuable lesson for myself. I know I could find an online tutorial but I feel that starting from scratch is a better leaning opportunity, but right now I am stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here are some point (i still suggest you find some page like [w3chool](http://www.w3schools.com/) or [here](http://way2tutorial.com/index.php) or whatever page you can find to learn more or fully understand your problem)

1. Menu 1 pushed away because you set your 2nd `ul` with `visibility:hidden` - it hidden but still take same space (width and height), so if you change that to `display:none` and remove `height:100px` in your 1st `ul` it will become one line and smooth (don't set height to `ul`, especially when it have 1 or more `ul` inside, it will ruin your menu)
2. Your Submenu 1 to the right of the Menu 1 because, uhm not sure how to say so i skip to solution to solve this. To position your submenu, i suggest use `position:absolute` with `margin` to position your submenu (beside your main menu if vertical menu or below if horizontal)

This is your new CSS after i modify a bit

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav {background-color: pink; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100px;}
ul {list-style: none; width: 50%; background: yellow; margin: 0 auto}
li {display: inline-block; background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 50px}
a {text-decoration: none;}
ul > li > ul {display: none; position: absolute; margin: 35px 0 0 -40px;}
ul > li:hover > ul {display: block;}
ul > li > ul li {display: block;}
```

And this the new [DEMO](http://liveweave.com/GhvHqm) 
Hope you lucky with learning HTML and CSS!